# Angular 2 SystemJS Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm creating an Angular 2 app and I get the `(SystemJS) Unexpected token <` error in the controller. I'm following the [quick start tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to create this app.

I have copied the package.json, tsconfig.json, typings.json, and systemjs.config.js directly from the tutorial to my project.

Here is the systemjs.config.js:

```js
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'app',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

And I have the following as my main.ts file:

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'crm-page',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class CRMModule { }


const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

platform.bootstrapModule(CRMModule);
```

The exact error message is:
[image]

After Clicking on (...) the following error message is shown:
[image]

And here is my code for my index:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- icons -->

</head>
<body>



<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

<script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>

<crm-page>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 225px; text-align: center; font-size: 40px;"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3" aria-hidden="true"></i> Loading...</div>
</crm-page>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message? Include any files it mentions in your question

Comment: @Phil thank you for help. I attached a picture of the exact error message in the question above.

Comment: It's likely you can get more information if you click to expand `(...)` in that error message. It could reveal the file that contains unexpected `<` in it, so you can track it down to determine the reason - most likely, HTML was returned instead of the javascript due to some error in the configuration.

Comment: @artem, thanks for your help and you were correct after clicking on (...) another error message is shown. Please check the question for the updated error message.

Comment: `Unable to load transpiler to transpile .../app/main.js` means that SystemJS detected es6 features in main.js file and it wants to compile it to es5 using traceur compiler, and the request to get traceur compiler returned some HTML (404 error message maybe?). In general traceur should not be needed if main.ts is compiled to main.js with typescript target set to `es5` (as it is in the tsconfig.json from that tutorial).  What's the content of `app/main.js` file and how it was created?

Comment: I used to see these errors when systemjs didn't find the needed file and it returned the index.html instead.
Check the network tab in chrome dev tools, check to see if any of the requested js files might be an html file.
I hope I explained myself well, this might lead you to some other ideas to solve this issue